# How to stop video onclick function in jwplayer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Javascript:

```
jwplayer("mvcontainer").setup({
            flashplayer: "https://media.dreamhost.com/mp5/player.swf",
            file: "video_file.flv",
            icons: true,
            autostart: true,
            controlbar: "bottom",
            height: 406,
            width: 628
         });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mvcontainer"></div>
```

The above coding is using to play `flv` video in my site. This coding working correctly but I have a problem. I removed the video then replaced some content in same page. The video is not stopped, it continuously playing in background.

How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
jwplayer().remove();
```

or

```
jwplayer().stop();
```

There's [JW Player JS API Documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28850/using-the-javascript-api)

Comment: jwplayer().remove(); its working fine. Thanks a lot for your help Mr.Vova Pavlikov.

Comment: If the Answer provided here has fixed your problem please mark it as such, it will help anyone who has a similar problem in future see what they need to do in order to fix it.